# Control update variables in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the following question, in terraform how to update variables tags only when the resource is changed?. For example, the below code has the tag UpdatedAt = timestamp(), the timestamp function is executed every time with the terraform apply command. How should I do so that the tag only changes when the resource it changes?, i.e. the timestamp() function only should be executed when the resource aws_instance have an updated

````
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami           = var.instance_ami
  instance_type = var.instance_size
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id
  key_name = var.ssh_key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.security_group_id
  user_data                   = file(var.file_path)
  

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.instance_root_device_size
    volume_type = "gp3"
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${ec2_name}-${var.project_name}-${var.infra_env}"
    Project     = var.project_name
    Environment = var.infra_env
    ManagedBy   = "terraform"
    UpdatedBy   = var.developer_email
    UpdatedAt   = timestamp()
  }
} ```
````

Comment: EC2 already automatically tracks the launch time of each EC2 instance without any special configuration, so I think it would be redundant to also track it in a tag. Are you sure that you need this extra tag in addition to the launch time field that EC2 already records for each instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. TF does not have functionality for you to conditionally apply/exclude changes during `apply` procedure.